# Block integrator overflow in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am working on the Matlab simulink block: Mean (variable frequency). The block is shown at http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/meanvariablefrequency.html

The first step of this algorithm is integrating the input signal. However, when the input signal is a constant, the integrator will accumulate until it overflows. Does anyone know how to solve this problem in such block.

I also attach the diagram of this block below:
[image]
Later, I will change it to discrete-time model and implement such algorithm in my DSP. If you have any suggestion, I am a good listener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are implementing is

```
y(t) = Integrate_{x=0->t} u(x) dx  -  Integrate_{y=0->t-T} u(y) dy          (1)
```

where `T` is the transport delay. This can be reordered by substituting `z = y + T` and due to the linearity of the integral to

```
y(t) = Integrate_{x=0->t} u(x) dx  -  Integrate_{z=T->t} u(z - T) dz
     = Integrate_{x=0->t} [ u(x) - u(x - T) ] dx + C                        (2)
```

where

```
C = Integrate_{z=0->T} u(z) dz
```

is a finite constant that depends on the initial conditions and can be assumed to be 0 if your signal `u` is zero for the initial time `t = 0 ... T`.

If we look at an input signal with DC-offset such as

```
u(t) = DC + sin(w*t)
```

then implementation `(1)` will first integrate and then subtract, which will saturate or lead to a loss of precision as you have noted. But `(2)` will first subtract and thus remove any DC

```
u(x) - u(x - T) = DC - DC + sin(w*t) - sin(w*t - w*T)
                = 0         sin(w*t) - sin(w*t - w*T)
```

and then integrate, without risking saturation. Thus I recommend to change the implementation as follows:

[image: simulink design]

Alternatively you could change the ideal integrator `1/s` to a low-pass filter with finite gain at DC, e.g. `1/(1+s)` although this (as well as the anti-windup controller suggested by @thewaywewalk) will distort your signal compared to the ideal behaviour.

*PS: Thanks to stackoverflow for not supporting proper math-notation...*  `:-/`

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement an **Anti-Windup** control. The easiest way is to use an **PID-Controller** and set the constant and differential gain to zero. For the Anti-Windup you have two options in general: back-calculation and clamping. For differences and reference have a look at this article: [Anti-windup control using a PID-Controller](http://de.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/anti-windup-control-using-a-pid-controller.html)